# Aws - health checks for wildfly project on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a load balancer for my EC2 instance which hosted wildfly project, but it always failed on healthy checks I think this cause wildfly project should listen to specific port only like this

http://(instance-Ip):8081/

I tried to make this checks with login page but it seems it's not reachable so I make it as defaults but still not responding

[image]

Health checks

[image]

Update to my question 
SecurityGroup for instance allow connect to port 443 to all

any hint why this could be happening

Comment: What happens if you browse the IP address on 443? (if SecurityGroup rules allow)

Comment: Security groups opened for ports 443 for anywhere, the same to 80

Comment: Also can you please clarify what port your application is listening to on EC2 instances? If the port your application is listening to is different than than the port ELB listens to, you will have to override it in the `health check` section.

Comment: looking at the question more closely, it looks like `wildfly` is listening on port 8081. You need to specify 8081 as the port instead of `traffic port`. This setting is under `Advanced Settings` if you are using AWS Console. I hope you have also mentioned 8081 as port for your target group.

Comment: Thanks that is the right answer